# Extend size of canvas in Illustrator - Illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator, creative-cloud, canvas

Is there a way to maximize the canvas in illustrator? So not the artboard but the dark grey board behind it. I know that the limitations of file size is under 5 metres.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. The pasteboard/canvas is dynamic and based upon what's necessary to the the artboard(s). You could create a new arbitrary artboard the size you want the canvas to be... and it'll extend to that.

Comment: Hi. Why do you want to do this?  What problem are you actually trying to solve by doing this?  At the moment your question reads like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 2):

In Illustrator you can enable "large canvas mode" by creating an artboard where one of the dimensions is larger than 227 inches.

Alternatively you can set up a grid of artboards that exceeds 227 inches in one dimension.

You can read more about it in [Adobe's help center](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/large-sized-artwork.html).